# Duplicity: Exclude files from verification

Tags: backup, duplicity

I use duplicity to backup a set of directories, using a daily cron job. I have another daily cron job to `duplicity verify --compare-data` the backup, as a sanity check, which runs shortly after the backup. I'd like to exclude some frequently changing files from the verification, so that I don't always get false positives in the resulting cron email. That is, I don't want to have those files reported in the number of differences found. I still want to backup those files (otherwise I'd simply exclude them from the backup in the first place).

Unfortunately, when verifying, duplicity applies the `--exclude`/`--include` options only to the file system side, not to the backup side. That is, when I exclude more files in the verification than were excluded in the backup, duplicity reports those files as missing (present in the backup but missing in the file system). Hence the `--exclude` option can't be used to exclude files from being verified altogether. There's the `--file-to-restore` option, which also applies to verification (allows to verify a specific path), but it only accepts a single path, not a set of patterns and no exclusions like with `--include`/`--exclude`.

Is there some other way to achieve what I want, that is, verify an existing backup against the file system, excluding certain files (preferably file patterns) from both sides of the verification?

Answer (score 1):

sorry to disappoint but you already researched both ways to limit duplicity's `verify` command. you may consider splitting your backups so you can verify independently.

surely it'd be helpful if `--in/exclude` would be implemented in a way that it could replace `--file-to-restore`. alas as of now the functionality is as it is.